# Running HashiCorp's Vault in ECS using Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, hashicorp-vault

I am currently exploring ECS using Fargate to deploy some services on it as it guarantees 99.99% availability and also you don't have to managed the instances.

I want to deploy secret management service like Vault on ECS using Fargate, has anybody tried that? and can guide me on following?

- json template for vault to be used with ECS
- custom backend using AWS Dynamo
- auto-unseal using AWS KMS

I'm using terraform to create all the above resources.

Comment: Have you tried using the Vault documentation? It doesn't cover Fargate specifically, but it covers [running Vault in kubernetes](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-reference-architecture?in=vault/kubernetes) which should give some insights, and it covers [auto-unseal using AWS KMS](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/autounseal-aws-kms?in=vault/auto-unseal)

Comment: Im able to run this on ECS Fargate successfully! using dynamo as backend and kms for unseal.

Comment: @AzizZoaib Would you be willing to share some of your knowledge? :)

Comment: Yes sure, let me know if you are stuck somewhere or needs help in anything.

Comment: I am running this same setup, only I am deploying via CloudFormation. I created a github repo here: https://github.com/savagete2860/hashicorp-vault-on-ecs-fargate

Did you also end up deploying this? I am wondering how to deal with running more than one running vault instance (5-10 instances), since the redirect load times make it basically unusable in my setup. When you hit a non-active node, the redirect can take 30 seconds or more depending how many tasks are running.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we are implemeting a Vault in in AWS ECS:

- KMS for auto-unseal
- S3 for persistant storage backend for Vault.
- ECS Fargate to run the vault binary

Here is its terraform code : https://github.com/Neutrollized/hashicorp-vault-with-fargate